# Mobx observable deep object

Tags: javascript, json, mobx

I looking for best solution how to implement @observable on deep json object structure (for example a tree) data tree could be go really deep. and each node has many properties, but I need to observe only one property in tree node. Simply if I do

```
@observable questionnaire = {}
```

it works, but i think that is waist. I need observe only 'selected' property. 
Here is json structure. Please correct me if i'm wrong here is questionnaire object simplified.

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "level 1",
    "description": "text",
    "type": "Question",
    "selected": false,
    "childNodes": [
      {
        "title": "level 2",
        "description": "text",
        "type": "Question",
        "selected": false,
        "childNodes": [
          {
            "title": "level 3",
            "description": null,
            "type": "Question",
            "selected": false,
            "childNodes": [
              {
                "title": "level 4 1",
                "childNodes": [],
                "description": null,
                "type": "Checkbox",
                "selected": false
              },
              {
                "title": "level 4 2",
                "childNodes": [],
                "description": null,
                "type": "Checkbox",
                "selected": false
              },
              {
                "title": "level 4 3",
                "childNodes": [],
                "description": null,
                "type": "Checkbox",
                "selected": false
              },
              ...
            ]
          }, ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to have a `Node` class implemented as follows:

```
class Node {
  @observable selected = false;
  @observable childNodes = asFlat([]);

  constructor(data) {
    // Recursively create `Node` objects for all children.
    data.childNodes = data.childNodes.map(child => new Node(child));
    Object.assign(this, data);
  }
}
```

Then you create a `Node` object from your top-level json object: `new Node(json)`.

This solution will only observe `selected` and `childNodes`. It's not ideal because you need to wrap your json object in `Node` objects. But I can't think of any other way to do it.

Comment: Do you think if we start observe childNodes then all properties in that node will become observable?

Comment: You are exactly right. We need to use the `asFlat` modifier to prevent that. I updated my answer.

Comment: Mouad Debbar Thank you for your answer. I accept your answer as a solution to my issue with minimal modification to your code. I don't think I need this line at all @observable childNodes = asFlat([]);  'selected' property will gets observable every time I 'new Node(child)' . Again thank you for your help. :-)

Comment: I'm glad my answer was helpful :)